# Where are entry_64.S and related .S files in Linux 4.4?

Tags: linux, system-calls

[Linux source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/entry/?v=4.4) for kernel version 4.4 lists "entry_64.S" file in /arch/x86/entry/ directory but I am unable to locate this file in my PC at following location:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic/arch/x86/entry
```

I tried using find command but it gave me no results. Can anyone tell me where can I find this file as well as entry_32.S file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These markings indicate a Ubuntu system, and the typical way of looking up a file in all of Ubuntu is entering your query at http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents

In your case, that leads to e.g. http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=entry_64.S which says the file isn't part of any packages.

If this was a bug, you'd go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic and file a bug report about it. However, it bears considering that the package is called **headers**, which is not typically correlated with assembly files.

What you probably want to do is run:

```
apt-get source linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic
```

This will provide you with the full Linux source of that kernel, which will likely include that assembly file, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The source files are not shown in running kernel but can be seen in source as you mentioned.